# change name of default primary key in laravel model generation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've generated a model from a table and have written the following in the controller to return all records:

```
vehicle_details::find($VehicleId);
```

This generates the error and query below.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vehicle_details.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `vehicle_details` where `vehicle_details`.`id` = 1 limit 1)
```

I was wondering how to change the id that is used by eloquent. It defaults to 'id' but the primary key in the table is 'vehicle_id'. I'm guessing I need to change the model class that I generated in some way?

On another note there could be an enhancement to be made here. It seems like a good feature would be for laravel to take into account what the primary key in the table it is generating the model for. Then from there, make the necessary change to the model class code that is generated rather than just assuming 'id' will always be the primary key in the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Already answered here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030716/change-default-primary-key-in-eloquent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
protected $primaryKey = "vehicle_id"
```

in your model

Answer (score 0):

In your models

```
<?php 
class vehicle_detail extends Models{
    $primaryKey ="vehicle_id"
}
```