# Method find error with with Eloquent in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a table Order and make a eloquent. The id (primary key) is not int, but varchar.

```
    $order=Order::find($id);// well, it works.
```

It works fine, and var_dump the data is right. The question is quote the property is wrong. I mean:

```
    var_dump($order->id); // get int(0), actually it a varchar in 32 characters
    var_dump($order->remark); // works well
```

So, i think there is something wrong when id is not int if use eloquent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default primary key in Eloquent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030716/change-default-primary-key-in-eloquent)

Comment: What is the name of your `id` column in your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `public $incrementing = false;` in your model.

Eloquent by default casts `id` (its `$primaryKey` in particular) to `int`, unless you explicitly state that you don't use auto incrementing ids.