# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column - Laravel Livewire Cart

Tags: php, laravel, cart, shopping-cart, laravel-livewire

I'm using framework Laravel 8 and Livewire

i want to make cart from Darryldecode Cart, and i have (menus) table in my phpmysql, when i want click "add cart", i get the error message :

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'menus.id' in
> 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `menus` where `menus`.`id` = 5
> limit 1)

Migration Menus

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id_menu');
        $table->string('menu_name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->string('menu_image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Cart View

```
<section class="fullheight">
<div class="row mx-3">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="lqd-column col-xs-12 mb-20">
            <div class="liquid-filter-items justify-content-between">
                <div class="liquid-filter-items-inner pt-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="search" class="form-control bg-athens-gray px-4" placeholder="Search Foods or Drinks">
                    </div>

                    <ul class="filter-list text-uppercase ltr-sp-1 filter-list-inline size-sm font-weight-bold py-4 mb-0">
                        <li class="active" data-filter="*"><span>All Categories</span></li>
                        <li data-filter=".Foods"><span>Foods</span></li>
                        <li data-filter=".Drinks"><span>Drinks</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @foreach($data_menu as $dm)
        <div class="lqd-column text-center col-md-3 col-sm-6 masonry-item '.$tm->kategori.'">
            <article class="liquid-lp mb-40">
                <figure class="liquid-lp-media">
                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $dm->menu_image) }}" alt="{{ $dm->menu_name }}">
                </figure>
            
                <header class="liquid-lp-header">
                    <h2 class="liquid-lp-title text-center h4 font-size-16">{{ $dm->menu_name }}</h2>
                    <h2 class="liquid-lp-title text-center h4 font-size-16 pt-2">Rp. {{ number_format($dm->price) }}</h2>
                </header>
            
                <footer class="liquid-lp-footer">
                    <div class="btn-cart">
                        <div wire:click="tambah_cart({{ $dm->id_menu }})" class="btn btn-default circle btn-bordered text-uppercase font-weight-bold font-size-12 border-thin lh-15 mb-2">
                            <span>
                                <span class="btn-txt">Add Cart</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </article>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card card-shadow">
            <div class="card-body px-5">
                <h2 class="">Cart</h2>

                <div class="fancy-box fancy-box-offer fancy-box-offer-header">
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell fancy-box-header" style="flex-grow: 1;">
                        <p>Menu Name</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell" style="flex-grow: 0.5;">
                        <p>Qty</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell">
                        <p>Price</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @forelse($data_cart as $dc)
                <div class="fancy-box fancy-box-offer fancy-box-heading-sm">
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell fancy-box-header" style="flex-grow: 1;">
                        <h3>
                            {{ $dc['name'] }}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell" data-text="Quantity" style="flex-grow: 0.5;">
                        <h5>
                            {{ $dc['qty'] }}
                        </h5>
                    </div>

                    <div class="fancy-box-cell" data-text="Price">
                        <h5>
                            Rp. {{ $dc['price'] }}
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="fancy-box-cell" data-text="Availability">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm circle btn-bordered text-uppercase font-weight-bold lh-15">
                            <span>
                                <span class="btn-txt">
                                    <svg class="bi bi-trash" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6z"/>
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1zM4.118 4L4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118zM2.5 3V2h11v1h-11z"/>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @empty
                <div class="fancy-box-cell fancy-box-header">
                    <p>Cart is empty</p>
                </div>
                @endforelse
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cart Controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Menu as MenuModel;
use Carbon\Carbon; 

class Cart extends Component
{
    public $tax = "0%";

    public function render()
    {
        $data_menu = MenuModel::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

        $condition = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition([
            'name' => 'pajak',
            'type' => 'tax',
            'target' => 'total',
            'value' => $this->tax,
            'order' => 1
        ]);

        \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->condition($condition);
        $items = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getContent()->sortBy(function ($cart) {
            return $cart->attributes->get('added_at');
        });

        if(\Cart::isEmpty()) {
            $cartData = [];
        } else {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $cart[] = [
                    'rowId' => $item->id_menu,
                    'name' => $item->menu_name,
                    'qty' => $item->quantity,
                    'pricesingle' => $item->price,
                    'price' => $item->getPriceSum(),
                ];
            }

            $cartData = collect($cart);
        }
        
        $sub_total = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getSubTotal();
        $total = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getTotal();

        $newCondition = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getCondition('pajak');
        $pajak = $newCondition->getCalculatedValue($sub_total);

        $summary = [
            'sub_total' => $sub_total,
            'pajak' => $pajak,
            'total' => $total
        ];

        return view('livewire.cart', [
            'data_menu' => $data_menu,
            'data_cart' => $cartData,
            'summary' => $summary
        ]);
    }
    
    public function tambah_cart($id) {
        $rowId = "Cart".$id;
        $cart = \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->getContent();
        $cekItemId = $cart->whereIn('id_menu', $rowId);

        if($cekItemId->isNotEmpty()) {
            \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->update($rowId, [
                'quantity' => [
                    'relative' => true,
                    'value' => 1
                ]
            ]);
        } else {
            $data_menus = MenuModel::find($id);
            \Cart::session(Auth()->id())->add([
                'id' => "Cart".$data_menus->id_menu,
                'name' => $data_menus->menu_name,
                'price' => $data_menus->price,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'attributes' => [
                    'added_at' => Carbon::now()
                ],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Menu Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'menus';
    protected $guarded = []; // Bisa di settings kolom mana saja yang mau di baca
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Web Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\Menu;
use App\Http\Livewire\Cart;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/menu', Menu::class);
    Route::get('/cart', Cart::class);
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

Comment: I see you are using `menus.id` column but you create table with `menus.id_menu` column. Also refer this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030716/change-default-primary-key-in-eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default name of primary key for models is 'id' but you have different primary key in your menus table (id_menu).
[You should specify the primary key in model](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys):

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_menu';
```

Comment: Now the problem is menu name not showed on cart